# Как в Access добавить несколько строк в таблицу?

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается добавить несколько строк в таблицу MS Access, хотя вроде бы синтаксис правильный.

Comment: Синтаксис неправильный. В `INSERT INTO … VALUES …` можно указать только одну строку

Comment: А как же тогда работает многострочный оператор INSERT в SQL?

Comment: Не существует просто SQL. У каждой СУБД свой диалект. MS Access такой. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: Если требуется вставка нескольких записей, используйте INSERT .. SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно указал @Akina используйте select в связке с Union All если вставить все записи, UNION если только уникальные

```
INSERT INTO "Изделия" ("Название", "Вес", "Количество", "Цена", "Дата_изготовления", "Фирма_изготовитель") VALUES
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Столовая ложка', 35, 100, 1100, '02.10.2001', 'Forio' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Столовая ложка', 35, 100,1100, '02.10.2001', 'Forio' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Столовая ложка', 35, 100,1100, '02.10.2001', 'Forio' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Столовая ложка', 35, 100,1100, '02.10.2001', 'Forio');
```

Comment: Пишет, что ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO, пробовал брать данные в скобки после SELECT, но всё равно не работает.

Comment: Так попробуйте.

Comment: Увы, всё равно ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции. Добавлял значения в таблицу запросами по одной строке.

Comment: Извините за запятую

Comment: Я изменял формат до вашего ответа, но всё равно не работает. Уже выполнил по другому, спасибо что попытались помочь.

Comment: Так попробуйте чтоб наверника. И опубликуйте свой ответ